# understanding pairwise independent, but not independent

Tags: probability, independence

In reading about events being pairwise independent but not independent,
I come across this equation.

$$P\left(A\bigcap B\bigcap C\right)\:=\:\left(X\right)\ne \:\left(Y\right)\:=\:P\left(A\right)P\left(B\right)P\left(C\right)$$

(X and Y being different possiblities)

[this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1276106/220038) explains it well, but I didn't quite understand this particular part from it.

> But: $$P\left(A\bigcap B\bigcap C\right)\:=\:P\left(A\bigcap
>  B\right)\:=\:\frac{1}{2}$$

My main question is, how can 
$P\left(A\bigcap B\bigcap C\right)$ and 
$P\left(A\right)P\left(B\right)P\left(C\right)$
yield different results? Aren't they suppose to be the same equation

Comment: They yield different results precisely because they are not independent.  If they were independent, we would have exactly $P(A \cap B \cap C) = P(A)P(B)P(C)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer explains that 
$P(A) = P(B) =P(C) = \frac{1}{2}.$

If we want to consider $P(A\cap B\cap C)$, then notice that
$$A\cap B\cap C = \{\text{First is $H$, second is $T$, one is $H$ and other $T$}\} = A\cap B.\tag{$\star$}$$
Thus, 
$$P(A\cap B\cap C) = P(A\cap B) = P(A)P(B) = \frac{1}{2}\cdot  \frac{1}{2} = \frac{1}{4}.$$
Clearly, this **does not** equal
$$P(A)P(B)P(C) = \frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{1}{2} = \frac{1}{8}.$$

Therefore $A,B,C$ are not independent.

Comment: P(A∩B∩C)=P(A∩B)?? what happens to C?

Comment: @lasec0203 Refer to $(\star)$. Notice that $A\cap B \subset C$.

Comment: @lasec0203 That's the point. $A$ says first flip is $H$, $B$ says that the second is $T$, and $C$ says one is $H$ and $T$. Notice that $C$ is repetitive, since $A\cap B$ satisfies condition $C$. So $A\cap B\cap C = A\cap B$.

Comment: thanks, but this is still confusing me.

Comment: @lasec0203 Notice that $A = \{HT, HH\}, B = \{HT, TT\}$, and $C = \{HT, TH\}$. Then the intersection $A\cap B\cap C = \{HT\}$, since this is the only outcome they have in common is $HT$. Thus $$P(A\cap B\cap C) = P(A\cap B) = P(HT) = \frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{1}{2} = \frac{1}{4}.$$

Comment: @lasec0203 Great, good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Your first question: From the linked answer, the events $A$,$B$, and $C$ are defined so that $(A \cap B) \subset C$, so necessarily $A \cap B \cap C = A \cap B$. (This is just set theory.)

Your main question: that is precisely the significance of independence. In general, $P(A \cap B \cap C) \ne P(A) P(B) P(C)$, as the example shows. However, if $A$, $B$, and $C$ are independent, then you do have $P(A \cap B \cap C) = P(A) P(B) P(C)$, by definition. They are not the "same equation" unless you have the assumption of independence.

[Similarly, $P(A \cap B) \ne P(A) P(B)$ in general, unless $A$ and $B$ are independent.]